Crear directorio temporal dentro de mi aplicacion Java
En Java versión 8 estoy creando un directorio temporal para almacenar unos PDFs que los necesito para más tarde:
He creado la siguiente clase:
public class CrearCarpetaTemporal {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Apéndice de método generado automáticamente
        try {
            //Creamos un directorio temporal
            Path tempDir = Files.createTempDirectory("Temp");
            
            //Imprimir la ruta del directorio temporal
            System.out.println("Ruta del directorio temporal: " + tempDir.toAbsolutePath());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Bloque catch generado automáticamente
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}

Se me crea una carpeta temporal de la siguiente manera:

C:\Users\XXXXX\AppData\Local\Temp\Temp1595077485470270787

Me gustaría saber cómo crear una carpeta temporal dentro de la misma ubicación de mi aplicación en Java para cuando tenga que utilizarse en otros entornos aparte de mi equipo local.
Muchas gracias.
Un saludo.

Hola Jesus, podes usar: XXX.class.getProtecttionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath() );**, debes reemplazar "XXX" por el nombre de la clase principal de tu aplicación, la que tiene el método main, esto te devuelve la carpeta donde está el .jar.

Buenas @MarcePuente ¿En qué parte lo pondría? gracias.

Hola, hay un error de sintaxis, en realidad es: XXX..class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath() );, el donde, es donde necesites obtener la dir del .jar, no hay que crearla, ya existe.

Puedes hacerlo de la siguiente manera, al llamar a Files.createTempDirectory en vez de usar "Temp", usa Paths.get("").
class CrearCarpetaTemporal {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        //Creamos un directorio temporal
        Path tempDir = Files.createTempDirectory(Paths.get(""), null);

        //Imprimir la ruta del directorio temporal
        System.out.println("Ruta del directorio temporal: " + tempDir.toAbsolutePath());
    }
}


Para obtener el directorio temporal por defecto en java puedes utilizar
System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir")
En windows, es %USER%\AppData\Local\Temp
En linux, es /tmp

Me refiero dentro de la carpeta de mi aplicación

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/320542/how-to-get-the-path-of-a-running-jar-file
